# If the first Stiefel-Whitney class of a subset $\gamma$ of a vector bundle $E$ is $w_1(\gamma)\neq 0$, is $w_1(E)\neq 0$ as well?

Tags: vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Define:

- A vector bundle $E$ over a m-dimension base space $M$,  $f: E\rightarrow M $
- A non-contractible loop $L$ in the base space $M$
- The vector bundle of the loop $L$ is $\gamma$  ,  $g: \gamma \rightarrow L$

Question:

- If the first Stiefel-Whitney class of the vector bundle bundle $\gamma$ is  $w_1(\gamma)\neq0$, do we have $w_1(E)\neq0$?

Comment: What do you mean by the vector bundle of the loop $L$? Do you mean the restriction of $E$ to $L$?

Comment: I mean if we define a vector bundle E, then we just take a part of the bundle, this part corresponds to a loop $L$ in the base space. I hope it is clear, could you help me to edit the question?

Comment: If $\pi : E \to M$ is the projection map, do you mean $\pi^{-1}(L)$? This is what I mean by the restriction of $E$ to $L$ (it is the part of $E$ which lies over $L$).

Comment: @Michael Albanese Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The restriction of a vector bundle $\pi : E \to M$ to $L \subseteq M$ is $E|_L := \pi^{-1}(L)$.

If $i : L \to M$ denotes the inclusion map, then $E|_L \cong i^*E$. To see this, note that the total space of the pullback bundle is given by $i^*E = \{(\ell, e) \in L\times E \mid i(\ell) = \pi(e)\}$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle#Formal_definition). An isomorphism $i^*E \to E|_L$ is given by $(\ell, e) \mapsto e$ with inverse given by $e \mapsto (\pi(e), e)$. With this in mind, we have

$$w_1(E|_L) = w_1(i^*E) = i^*w_1(E).$$

So if $w_1(E) = 0$, then $w_1(E|_L) = i^*w_1(E) = i^*0 = 0$. Therefore, if $w_1(E|_L) \neq 0$, then $w_1(E) \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do we need that the loop $L$ is not homotopic to the constant loop (a point)? For example, if the base space $M=S^2$, then we know $w_1(E)$ must be zero. In this case, is it possible to let $w_1(E|_L)\neq 0$ (like a $E|_L$ is a mobius shape)? If so, which part of the deduction is not valid anymore to let $w_1(E)\neq 0$.

Comment: If $L$ is contractible in $M$, then $i : L \to M$ is nullhomotopic, so $w_1(E|_L) = i^*w_1(E) = 0$ and hence $E|_L$ is trivial. That is, the condition that $E|_L \to L$ is non-trivial implies the loop $L$ is not contractible in $M$.